# mySQL giving improper results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, where-clause

I have a bit of an issue with an mySQL command that doesn't seem to work right. I'm building a simple PHP search feature and need it to check two columns (same table), if something in either column is LIKE it, then I need it to output it. It seems to work if I just have it looking in one column, but if I put the OR statement in, it still works it just doesn't seem to be pulling the correct data every time. It's a bit difficult to explain, so I'll use an example down below.

## PHP and mySQL:

```
     <?php
         $in=$_GET['txt'];
         $msg="";
         if(strlen($in)>0 and strlen($in) <20 ){
         $t=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM es_sermons WHERE searchTags like '$in%' OR serviceName like '$in%'");
         while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($t)){
            $msg.=$nt[name]."$nt[serviceName]<br>";
         }
         }
         echo $msg
     ?>
```

## Database Table:

```
id  |  serviceName                  |   searchTags
1   |  Prayer Positions             |   Prayer, Fasting, Morning, Pastor, Donnie
2   |  Ephesians Part 9             |   Ephesians, Pastor, Donnie, Wednesday
3   |  Gaining a Clear Vision       |   Missions, Ministry, Donnie, Pastor, Morning
4   |  Downpour Part 7              |   downpour, Tim, 3, Evening, Sunday
5   |  God is For Me Part 4         |   Pastor, Donnie, Morning, God is For Me
```

## Example Search Results:

Searched for: "Pastor" -> Results Were: 2, 5 -> Should of been 2, 3, 5 -> Why was 3 left out?

Searched for: "Donnie" -> Results Were: 5 -> Should of been 1,5 -> Why was 1 left out?

Searched for: "Wednesday" -> Results Were: NONE -> Should of been 2 -> Why was 2 left out?

The results are very inconsistent. If anyone could help, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below :-

```
$t=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM es_sermons WHERE searchTags like '%$in%' OR serviceName like '%$in%'");  // % sign on both side of the search word
```

Comment: i am wondering, how did he get the result 2 and 5 for "Pastor" if the issue is the missing %, it should only give 5 right?

Comment: Great, thank you! That worked perfect! If you don't mind, could you explain the reason/difference between the % before and after?